# how to fix the problem that inputting comment on the Instagram post

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am just a beginner for programming. Actually, I try to make an automatically comment on Instagram. However, if I run the code below via chrome/firefox. it will contain difference error

```
import time
import random
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Commenter:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    """closing browser"""
    def closeBrowser(self):
        self.driver.close()

    """login in to Instagram"""
    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(2)
        login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher']")
        login_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
        user_name_elem.clear()
        user_name_elem.send_keys(self.username)
        passworword_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
        passworword_elem.clear()
        passworword_elem.send_keys(self.password)
        passworword_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)


    """write comment in text area using lambda function"""
    def write_comment(self, comment_text):
        try:
            comment_button = lambda: self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Comment')
            comment_button().click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
##Add a comment…
        try:
            comment_box_elem = lambda: self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@aria-label='留言⋯⋯']")
            comment_box_elem().send_keys('')
            comment_box_elem().clear()
            for letter in comment_text:
                comment_box_elem().send_keys(letter)
                time.sleep((random.randint(1, 7) / 30))

            return comment_box_elem

        except StaleElementReferenceException and NoSuchElementException as e:
            print(e)
            return False

`com = Commenter(username='your login', password='your pw')
com.login()
time.sleep(3)
com.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/ByhuUY3nmEJ/")
time.sleep(5)
com.write_comment("123123123123123dd")`
```

it is hoped that I can write a comment on the post via Firefox/ chrome.

When I use Firefox, it will occur **"Element  is not reachable by keyboard Instagram"**

While I use Chrome, it will occur "
**selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.80)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)"**

It is highly appreciated that if you may give a solution to resolve my concern. I have searched the relevant questions, but I still did not get any idea to fix this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @DebanjanB, I think that the question is not duplicate, if possible please remove the duplicate tag, as I want to post an answer. But to fix this problem, you need to make comment box visible by clicking on it (just like in real life!). Add `time.sleep(5)` Before the comment, then add `comment_box_elem().click()` after the comment, I have tested the above would work

Comment: First of all you spoke about many things in the same time _Element is not reachable by keyboard_ , _ElementNotInteractableException_ etc. Please [edit the question](/posts/56536961/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. As of now I have added a duplicate target of each of the errors. Let me know if you still think otherwise.